# Calling function from expression in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it ok to call a function from expression or is it bad coding?

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{callFunction()}}
</div>

angular.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.callFunction = function() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? you want the function to be called once Angular interpolates your expression?

Answer (score 0):

Its bad practice to call a function from an expression as it would lead to multiple event call when the DOM loads. This would print "Hello" more than once on the console.

You are binding the event whenever load is called, to fire it once, you should bind it using `ng-init`.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-init="callFunction()"></div>
</div>
```